# How to avoid dummy type parameter added only for dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am working on refactoring some code. I discovered that one of my team colleagues created an interface like this:

```
public interface IConfiguration<T>
{
    string Url { get; }

    string Password { get; }
}
```

This T parameter seems to be redundant, but then I discovered that it is actually used in dependency injection configuration (it is ASP.NET core 2.2 application), like this:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
     builder.Services
          .AddSingleton<IConfiguration<Person>, PersonConfiguration>()
          .AddSingleton<IConfiguration<Product>, ProductConfiguration>()
          .AddSingleton<IConfiguration<Order>, OrderConfiguration>()
}
```

I don't know why but, I have strong distaste about this approach. Could any one suggest some more clean design (conforming to the SOLID principles) to this?

Comment: The type parameter isn't dummy. That's not the huge problem -in fact, the *real* Configuration classes use something similar. A far more serious problem is using the name `IConfiguration` for application interfaces. An interface with that name already exists in the Configuration namespace. Using interfaces for injected config DTOs is *already* available through eg the `IOptionXYZ` interfaces

Comment: The name is different - I changed the names to make code short and clean

Comment: Are implementations any different?  ```PersonConfiguration```, ```ProductConfiguration``` and ```OrderConfiguration```?

Comment: That obfuscated the question instead of making it short or clean. Why don't you ask your colleague what the interface is for? As I explained, .NET Core Configuration uses something similar through the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to abstract caching/monitoring for configuration objects. Even if the implementations are the same, a *middleware* may be using that interface. Or not. We just can't guess just by looking at an ... abstraction of the actual interface

Comment: @jalsh - no - they are exactly the same, and just return different strings.

Comment: _A far more serious problem is using the name IConfiguration for application interfaces._ is there any other reason that the name is already used **in another namespace** , I thought that's what namespaces are meant for?

Comment: @Marcin they can't be the same while returning different things

Comment: @jalsh when used in the *same* class where the system's `IConfiguration` is used, this is a problem for the *developers*. It causes confusion and leads to bugs

Comment: Please - imagine that this is not IConfiguration but IMyConfiguration, ok? This is completely not relevant to my question

Comment: If the type-param is really redundant - which it seems as it isn´t used throughout the entire interface at all - you should delete it. Pretending to be generic when there´s no use for generics serves no goal, IMHO and only makes people wonder "what the ... is this generic pyramater".

Comment: @Marcin, think of it this way, when you want to inject IConfiguration in your classes, you need to get a specific implementation, no way any DI container would be able to tell which implementation it should bind for that, so if you have one implmentation you can just use (IConfiguration) or else you're bound to have a template interface to diffrenciate

Comment: `conforming to the SOLID principles` nothing says the design isn't already following SOLID principles. There's not enough information here. This could simply be a way to add *common* auditing or source information to the DTOs, that's needed by consumers. Perhaps some middleware is going to *modify* those attributes. Or a better solution could be to extract what looks like credentials to a different class. The only information we have right now is the names

Comment: I get all your points, but the I agree the most with @HimBromBeere - for me it is a code smell, and a trick, which obscures readability. The accepted answer below, is for me the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would inherit from the IConfiguration interface for each specific configuration (Person, Product, Order), like this:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    string Url { get; }

    string Password { get; }
}

public interface IPersonConfiguration : IConfiguration {}
public interface IProductConfiguration : IConfiguration {}
public interface IOrderConfiguration : IConfiguration {}
```

And then in the Configure method:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
 {
      builder.Services
           .AddSingleton<IPersonConfiguration, PersonConfiguration>()
           .AddSingleton<IProductConfiguration, ProductConfiguration>()
           .AddSingleton<IOrderConfiguration, OrderConfiguration>()
 }
```

Advantages to this approach:

- Easily extendable code. For example, adding extra property to the Person config alone is much easier (and possible).
- Following the previous point, the refactoring should be much easier and cleaner.
- *(At least looks much cleaner)*

Disadvantages of this approach:

- You are going to have to create interface for each configuration, which may be a bit tedious. In my opinion, this will save you a huge chuck of time in the long run. It’s a technical investment.

Answer (score 0):

The [ASP.NET Core way of doing Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is using the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Personally, I think the "cleanest" in the form of "least surprising" way to configure things in ASP.NET Core is using the pattern already provided instead of rolling one's own favorite.

You may want to ask your colleague why they did not use the provided mechanism. Maybe there was a good reason or maybe they just did not know better.

Comment: You´re once again stuck on this `Configuration`-thing, which doesn´t seem like OPs actual intent. Just leave asside the naming-issue here and think of the interface as if it were any other one, e.g. just `IMyInterface`. Having said this your answer boils down to "ask your collegue", which seems more like a comment IMHO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I would guess the OPs intent is to have a good solution in their environment, which they described in the body and in the tags as ASP.NET Core. And a good solution is *not* to reinvent the wheel, no matter how great that new wheel may follow certain principles. The best solution is to use the existing wheel that is *already* following certain patterns. The accepted solution *through the lens of ASP.NET Core* to me looks like there is something hidden. There must be some reason why the existing system was not used. In a code review I would certainly question that choice.

Comment: No, this is not relevant to any ASP.NET configuration. Lets assume that instead of IConfiguration  I have IMyCoolInterface and its implementations MyCoolPerson, MyProductPerson and MyOrderPerson - the classes names are also dummy. It was not the point.